# Modify panel's row after panel has been created

Tags: python, interface

I have an addon which creates a panel with properties on Blender startup:

```
class OBJECT_PT_runcamera(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Some Name"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "render"

    def draw_header(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="", icon="MESH_GRID")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row1 = layout.row()
        row1.prop(context.scene, "myCustomPropertysName")
```

Now, after the panel has been created, I want to change the row's `enabled` value when user clicks some specific button -- ie, some properties (shown in rows) in the panel will be disabled/enabled by some function called from another property/button.

I've tried different ways to write the command but nothing worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
bpy.types.Scene.show_row = bpy.props.BoolProperty()

row1.enabled = context.scene.show_row
```

And your other function will just set the `show_row` property. Thats it.

Comment: OK, my code now:
`bpy.types.Scene.show_row2 = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=True)`.
Then I define a function to switch `enabled`:
`def switchCustomProp(self, context):
context.scene.show_row2 = False`.
Then the switch:
`bpy.types.Scene.mySwitch = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=True, update=switchCustomProp)`. Then the panel is loaded where row2 gets set to some other property (myCustomProperty) and `row2.enabled=context.scene.show_row2`.
Now, when I click the bool property in row1, row2 does not get enabled/disabled :/

Comment: Ah, I had one extra `row2.enabled=True` inside the panel's code which overwrote the `row2.enabled=context.scene.show_row2`.
Deleted it and it works now. THX!